# Incorrect integer value when insert data to mysql database python

Tags: python

I have sample code like this:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root', db='marbola')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open('./Team_Attributes.csv') as csv_data:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data)
    next(csv_reader, None)
    for row in csv_reader:
        insert=(
            "INSERT INTO Team_Attributes(id,team_fifa_api_id,team_api_id,date,buildUpPlaySpeed,buildUpPlaySpeedClass,buildUpPlayDribbling,buildUpPlayDribblingClass,buildUpPlayPassing,buildUpPlayPassingClass,buildUpPlayPositioningClass,chanceCreationPassing,chanceCreationPassingClass,chanceCreationCrossing,chanceCreationCrossingClass,chanceCreationShooting,chanceCreationShootingClass,chanceCreationPositioningClass,defencePressure,defencePressureClass,defenceAggression,defenceAggressionClass,defenceTeamWidth,defenceTeamWidthClass,defenceDefenderLineClass)"
            + " VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        )
        cursor.execute(insert, row[:25])

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

I used above code to insert data into mysql database from csv file. The csv file is the import result from sqlite database of football analysis from kaggle.com. But there is an error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'buildUpPlayDribbling' at row 1")

This is the csv sample image:
[image: csv image]

Whats wrong with the code? How to solve this error? I used python 3.5

Comment: Either you got some of those columns out of order, or you got some of the tuple elements out of order, or it's exactly what the error says and the value you're passing for the `volleys` columns isn't an integer.

Comment: I have checked it and the elements have in order, and the volleys is integer value

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. You haven't given us enough information to debug this, you just claim you debugged it yourself and there's nothing wrong, but you want us to tell you what's wrong anyway? Please read the [mcve] help.

Comment: I have tried it for another table, and there is same error. Then I checked the csv and there is blank column in error field. Is %s right if the field is blank?

Comment: There's no such thing as a blank integer. It sounds like you're passing it strings. Sometimes that will work anyway, but it's not the _right_ thing to do. And, if the column is not nullable, it's definitely not going to work.

Comment: I mean that the csv field is blank, not blank integer

Comment: OK, you say you're passing integer values—what integer value are you passing for a blank CSV field?

Comment: What is the value of `tuple(row)` before the above statement?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I have get the error. It happen because the value inserted to table is empty. So, how can I insert empty or NULL to integer column in table?

Comment: Either decide what integer value the blank corresponds to, or allow NULL values when you create the table.

Comment: I want to able insert NULL to integer column. I have change all empty cell to NULL in csv, but when I execute my code again the error above is showed with 'NULL'.

Comment: Was the MySQL table created with NOT NULL, or does it allow NULL values?